# Cannot get all the rows but can get all single row by using iloc?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Today I have faced an issue while using `pandas`. The problem is very simple, `df.iloc[:][0]` gives me such error.

```
  File "C:\workspaces\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3805, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\workspaces\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3805, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
  KeyError: 0
```

To check which row cannot using `iloc`. I tried the following

```
for i in range(content_df.shape[0]):
    try:
        df.iloc[i][0]
    except:
        print(i)
```

Here nothing prints at all!

One thing also makes me very surprised. I would like to using `df.iloc[:][2:]` to remove the first two columns. However, it removes the first **two rows** in this way.

Anyone knows why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `df.iloc[:, 0]` or `df.iloc[:, 2:]` instead

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs My fault. This is very fundamental.

Comment: You are trying to impose Python List-like slicing in Pandas which is incorrect. See the `iloc` documentation or for example [click here](https://www.marsja.se/how-to-use-iloc-and-loc-for-indexing-and-slicing-pandas-dataframes/)

Answer (score 1):

`df.iloc[:, 2:]` removes the first two columns

`df.iloc[2:,:]` or `df.iloc[2:]` removes the first two rows...

```
df.iloc[r:r, c:c]
         ^    ^
         |    |
slices rows   |
            slices columns
```

Comment: Shouldn't it say: `df.iloc[:, 2:]` removes the **first** two columns?

Comment: oh whoops, I just realized

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to skip first two rows keeping all columns:

   `df.iloc[2:, :]`
2. If you want to skip first two columns keeping all rows:

   `df.iloc[:,2:]`